# How to use selector on object instance in swift

Tags: ios, swift, runtime

As we know a `string` object have methods like `uppercased`, `lowercased`, `capitalise`.

I want to call selector at run time. For ex:

```
let aSelector = Selector("capitalise")

let str = "Good Morning"
//now i want to apply aSelector on str:
let finalString = str.aSelector
```

How can i achieve it?
Thanks.

Comment: How would you use this?

Comment: I have two constants file for two target. In these files i want to define selector let's say capitalise and uppercase. Now in my code which is common to both targets, I have a string it can be capitalise or uppercase, without any if else. ex : str.thatSelectorInMyConstantFile @vacawama

Comment: If you want a better answer, you'll want to explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve, rather than how you're trying to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have two constants file for two target. In these files i want to
>   define selector let's say capitalise and uppercase. Now in my code
>   which is common to both targets, I have a string it can be capitalise
>   or uppercase, without any if else. ex :
>   `str.thatSelectorInMyConstantFile`

How about using a closure:

```
let stringOp = { (str: String) in str.capitalized }
```

**OR**

```
let stringOp = { (str: String) in str.uppercased() }
```

Then you'd use it like:

```
let str = "hello world"
let finalString = stringOp(str)
print(finalString)
```

**Output:**

> > ```
> > Hello World
> > ```

**OR**

> > ```
> > HELLO WORLD
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call selectors on objects that inherit from `NSObject`, so you would not be able to use a selector on a string.

In general, you are able to do:
`object.perform(#selector(ViewController.mySelectorMethod))`

But you should explain what you are trying to achieve - selectors aren't used in the way you've described, and there is probably a more standard implementation of what you're aiming for.

Comment: I have two constants file for two target. In these files i want to define selector let's say capitalise and uppercase. Now in my code which is common to both targets, I have a string it can be capitalise or uppercase, without any if else. ex : str.thatSelectorInMyConstantFile